# Text searching to compare against Mysql database tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, text

Let's say I have a string containing words. Some of these words may be compound words.

I also have a MySQL database which contains a table which contains a column called words. This column may contain words that appear in my string, including compound words.

I would like to be able to find out which rows to retrieve from the database, when I only have the string. Splitting it on space characters is not an option, because this will make it impossible to detect if any compound words from the database appear in the string.

Any suggestions as to how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the following approach.  Let's assume that your string has space as a separator and never contains a comma.

```
select *
from words w
where find_in_set(w.word, replace(<your string>, ' ', ',')) > 0;
```

If the delimiters in your string are a bit more complicated -- say it does have punctation, you might be better off with `regexp` rather than `find_in_set`:

```
select *
from words w
where concat(',', <your string>, ',') REGEXP concat('[ ,.!?]', w.word, '[ ,.!?]')
```

Comment: I think I'm going to try the regular expressions. Silly I haven't thought about it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to the relevance between the input string and the DB record. This is more suited to a solution like Lucene/SOLR.

That said, you might get some mileage from using FULLTEXT indexes and searches:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: Not the relevance, simply the occurrence. The string "My car rams the tree." and the table containing the values "car" and "tree" would desirebly return the two rows that correspond with these values.